# Error While Initializing Record Value

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have create a record in the package and declare variables of the type in one of the procedures of the package and when I try to initialize some  value of the record I get the following error:

```
[Error] PLS-00103 (372: 14): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref
   char time timestamp
```

The Package Body As follows :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY package_a
AS

TYPE location_details IS RECORD
(region_id VARCHAR(40),
lat VARCHAR2(10),
ranges VARCHAR2(5)
) ;


PROCEDURE do_actions (p_action_id IN NUMBER)
   AS

variable_1  location_details 

BEGIN
variable_1.ranges := '5';

END;
END package_a;
```

I am not able to identify the cause of error here.

Comment: code looks like correct may be you can try declare record type in package specification if this package is getting used form other program unit. you may need to put more code.

Comment: I have also declare the record in package specification. But same issue.

Answer (score 0):

add ; after

```
variable_1  location_details;
```

in do_actions procedure.

Comment: I have tried this and facing the same issue. The semi, colon is not the issue I think Nagendra has missed that while posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY APP.package_a
AS
TYPE location_details IS RECORD
(region_id VARCHAR(40),
lat VARCHAR2(10),
ranges VARCHAR2(5)
) ;

    enter code here

PROCEDURE do_actions (p_action_id IN NUMBER)
   AS
variable_1  location_details ;
BEGIN
variable_1.ranges := '5';
END;
END package_a;
```